# Running Javascript twice from Developer's console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I'm playing little nice Javascript game Candy Box (http://candies.aniwey.net/) and I checked the code little bit.

When I want to go on quest it sends this `quest.begin(true)`. So I tried to use it in developer's console to check if it works and it works. So I got another idea. That quest takes about 10 seconds, so I send this to the console `quest.begin(true);setTimeout(15000);` because I wanted to create something like this `quest.begin(true);setTimeout(15000); * 2`. So maybe you got the point what I want to create. I want to automatize doing quests but I dont know how to run it twice or more times. I even tried to do this:

```
var questLoop = quest.begin(true) + setTimeout(15000);
```

and then run it `questLoop * 2`, but it doesn't work. So can anyone help me how to run it twice or more times? Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be it, as verbose as it can be. Just copy-paste everything and it will run:

```
//creating our own scope just in case of collisions
(function(){

  //declare our configuration
  var i = 0;
  var limit = 2;

  //create an interval that runs the code every 15 seconds
  var now = setInterval(function(){
    quest.begin(true);

    //if we reached the limit, stop the interval from running
    if(++i === limit) clearInterval(now);
  },15000);

}());
```